# Upgrading PrimeFaces v8 to v10: Custom extender function in Schedule component not working

Tags: primefaces, fullcalendar

I was using custom extender function in my Schedule Component, the example codes are like below:

```html
<p:schedule id="myCal"
             value="#{calendar.value}"
             leftHeaderTemplate="today"
             rightHeaderTemplate="prev next"
             clientTimeZone="local"
             centerHeaderTemplate="title"
             draggable="false"
             showHeader="true"
             initialDate="#{calendar.initialDate}"
             tooltip="true"
             style="width:100%"
             styleClass="myCal"
             extender="schedulerExt">
</p:schedule>
```

Inside schedulerExt has all the callbacks for example to set the holidays and events, the below are the example codes:

```html
<script>
function schedulerExt( ) {
                this.cfg.views = {
                    month: {
                        displayEventEnd: true
                    }
                },

                this.cfg.dayRender = function (info) {
                    var hol = isHoliday(info.date);
                    if (hol >= 0) {
                        info.el.classList.remove('fc-past');
                        info.el.classList.remove('fc-day');
                        info.el.classList.remove('fc-sun');
                        info.el.classList.add('holiday');
                        info.el.classList.add(getHolidayStyle(hol));
                        info.el.setAttribute('title', getHoliday(hol));
                        var moment = new Date(info.date);
                        MyDateString = moment.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (moment.getMonth() +1) ).slice(-2) + "-" +('0' + moment.getDate()).slice(-2);

                        $('[data-date='+MyDateString+']').css({"color": "red", "font-weight":"bold"});
                    } else {
                        var schoolHol = isSchoolHoliday(info.date);
                        if (schoolHol >= 0) {
                            info.el.classList.remove('fc-past');
                            info.el.classList.remove('fc-day');
                            info.el.classList.remove('fc-sun');
                            info.el.classList.add('school-holiday');
                            info.el.setAttribute('title', 'School Holiday');
                            var moment = new Date(info.date);
                            MyDateString = moment.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (moment.getMonth() +1) ).slice(-2) + "-" +('0' + moment.getDate()).slice(-2);

                            $('[data-date='+MyDateString+']').css({"font-weight":"bold"});
                        }
                    }
                },

                this.cfg.datesRender = function (info) {
                    var minDate = moment().add(-2, 'year');
                    var maxDate = moment().add(1, 'year');
                    if (minDate >= info.view.activeStart && minDate <= info.view.activeEnd) {
                        $('.fc-prev-button').prop('disabled', true);
                        $('.fc-prev-button').addClass('fc-state-disabled');
                    } else {
                        $('.fc-prev-button').removeClass('fc-state-disabled');
                        $('.fc-prev-button').prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                    if (maxDate >= info.view.activeStart && maxDate <= info.view.activeEnd) {
                        $('.fc-next-button').prop('disabled', true);
                        $('.fc-next-button').addClass('fc-state-disabled');
                    } else {
                        $('.fc-next-button').removeClass('fc-state-disabled');
                        $('.fc-next-button').prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                },

                this.cfg.eventRender = function (info) {
                    info.el.setAttribute('title', info.event.extendedProps.description);
                    if (info.event.title.indexOf("PENDING") !== -1) {
                        var spanElement = (function() { var span = document.createElement('span'); span.className = 'fa fa-share-square-o'; span.textContent = '\u00A0'; return span; })();
                        info.el.querySelector(".fc-title").innerHTML = info.el.querySelector(".fc-title").innerHTML.replace('PENDING', '');
                        info.el.querySelector(".fc-title").parentNode.insertBefore(spanElement, info.el.querySelector(".fc-title"));
                    } else {
                        if (info.event.title.indexOf("Childcare") !== -1) {
                            var spanElement = (function() { var span = document.createElement('span'); span.className = 'fa fa-child'; span.textContent = '\u00A0'; return span; })();
                            info.el.querySelector(".fc-title").parentNode.insertBefore(spanElement, info.el.querySelector(".fc-title"));
                         } else if (info.event.title.indexOf("Annual") !== -1) {
                             var spanElement = (function() { var span = document.createElement('span'); span.className = 'fa fa-plane'; span.textContent = '\u00A0'; return span; })();
                             info.el.querySelector(".fc-title").parentNode.insertBefore(spanElement, info.el.querySelector(".fc-title"));
                         }
                     }
                };
}
</script>
```

It was working until I upgraded to PrimeFaces v10 where FullCalendar is upgraded to v5. All the callback functions are not called.

I have read through the migration guide of both [PrimeFaces](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/../migrationguide/10_0_0) and [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/upgrading-from-v4#view) and I could not find a way to make use of [Day-cell render hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/day-cell-render-hooks) and [Event render hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/event-render-hooks) which are newly introduced in FullCalendar v5. I have tried to change the naming of the callback functions but none of them works, would appreciate it if anyone could help me out cause I am still new in this.

Comment: Not fully sure what you are trying to do here, but can't you just set `styleClasses` on the server side? I don't think the PrimeFaces Event model has a disabled state. That's something you might want to create a feature request for.

Comment: Also check the FullCalendar v4 to V5 migration guide to see what you need to change.